# Linq to XML dynamic where query building

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

I have searched a while and found many great answers to this question but each solution errors when I try to mimick the code in my solution.

I am passing values to a function that should

1. Establish the LINQ to the XML file
2. Select the fileds
3. Filter by the values passed to the function
4. Create list for displaying

My Code is as follows:

```
Dim xelement As XElement = xelement.Load(get_local_data_year_path() & "\" & "PAYMENT.xml")
Dim elements = From objdata In xelement.Elements("PAYMENT") 
               Select New With {
                   .id = Trim(objdata.Element("id").Value), 
                   .Date = objdata.Element("paymentdate").Value,
                   .account_id = objdata.Element("account_id").Value
               }

If straccount_id.Length > 0 Then
   elements.Where(Function(P As PAYMENT) P.account_id.Equals(straccount_id))
End If

Dim result = (elements).ToList
```

The line I have issues with is the where clause as it produces the error

```
Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Where' can be called with these arguments:
Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As System.Func(Of <anonymous type>, Integer, Boolean)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of <anonymous type>)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Nested function does not have a signature that is compatible with delegate 'System.Func(Of <anonymous type>, Integer, Boolean)'.
Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As System.Func(Of <anonymous type>, Boolean)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of <anonymous type>)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable'.
```

I guess I am unsure how to declare PAYMENT when it is a XML file and why the line does not work at all.

Any help would be appreciated. VB.NET example preffered if possible.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your XML?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little confusing (where is `straccount_id` set?), but the following line should give a list of anonymous types (which is what you create in your first query) that match `straccount_id`:

```
Dim straccount_id As String = "123456"

Dim results = elements.Where(Function(e) e.account_id.Contains(straccount_id)).ToList()
```

You could also accomplish the same thing by using the `Where` clause in your query and converting that to a list:

```
Dim elements = (From objdata In xelement.Elements("PAYMENT")
               Where objdata.Element("account_id").Value.Contains(straccount_id)
               Select New With {
                    .id = Trim(objdata.Element("id").Value),
                    .Date = objdata.Element("paymentdate").Value,
                    .account_id = objdata.Element("account_id").Value
               }).ToList()
```

**EDIT**

You can combine multiple conditions in one `.Where`. For example, if you wanted to get every payment that had an id of "1" and an account_id of "123456" (trivial example), you would do this:

```
results = elements.Where(Function(e) e.account_id.Contains(straccount_id) And e.id = "1").ToList()
```

I'm not sure what you mean by `user had entered a value in an IF statement`, but you can certainly take inputs and use them in the above line.  The key (from my testing in VS2012) seems to be you declare `Function(e)` once, and put the criteria after it, joined by `And` or `Or` as needed.

Comment: I have one question. In this function I am passing multiple variables so if I execute elements.Where for each test case does it overwrite the previouse where? If it does then I am wondering if there is a way to implement a multy where scenario based on 4 variables passed to this function?

Comment: @StephenMcAllister - I'll look later this evening, but you might try `Where(Function(e) e.account_id.Contains(straccount_id) And Function(e) e.<someother criteria).ToList()` VB.NET isn't my strong suite (I'm more C#), so this is an educated guess.

Comment: OK. That may not work as I was wanting to evaluate that the user had entered a value in an IF statement. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @StephenMcAllister - I've edited my answer showing how to evaluate multiple conditions in a single Where clause.

Comment: Sorry that I have not made myself as clear as what I thought. This function has four variables passed to it which are selections from the screen that a user would choose to filter the returning data into a grid. What i would like to do for each conditional filter (which are four seperate fields) set up a IF account_id > 0 then results = elements.Where(Function(e) e.account_id.Contains(straccount_id)).ToList  and then on a new line IF payment_id > 0 then results = elements.Where(Function(e) e.payment_id.Contains(strpayment_id)).ToList. I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: Ah...ok.  Can the filter be any combination of the four fields (i.e., account_id and paymentid, or just paymentid, etc), or is it only one field per select (in other words, they can only filter on one of the criteria at any given time)?

Comment: It can be any combination of the four. Could be 1, could be all 4. Thanks for this help Tim.

Comment: @StephenMcAllister - that makes it a little more challenging, but I'm pretty sure using anonymous methods and delegates will be a key. I'm about to get some much needed sleep, so I'll look at this again tomorrow.  It's an interesting question which makes it fun :)

Comment: @StephenMcAllister - I haven't had a chance to finish my thoughts on this - I've got a project at work that is almost done but has some issues.  I will try to get some more coherent ideas out this weekend - in the meantime, you could do it with a bunch of if statements and calling the right dynamic query based on which and how many arguments you have, but that would get ugly real quick.  I'm sure there's a better way to do it.  Sorry for the delay.